# Android - Почему ImageSpan становятся невидимыми, если их 3 и больше?

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток, имеется строка (уже без тегов), в которую нужно вставить ImageSpan в количестве 3 и более единиц. Позиция для вставки у меня находится в переменной spanStart и меняется в цикле. Вот так вот я вставляю ImageSpan:

```
Drawable smileIcon = getResources().getDrawable(getDrawableSmileResource(currentTag.substring(34, currentTag.indexOf(".", 34))));
smileIcon.setBounds(0, 0, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.smileSize), (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.smileSize));
spanBuilder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(smileIcon, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM), spanStart, spanStart + 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Вставляю с позиции spanStart и до позиции spanStart + 1, т.е. занимает это дело 1 символ - пробел. Если же имеется 3 и более ImageSpan'а, то они все становятся невидимыми... Так же заметил, что если всю строку забить такими ImageSpan'ами, то она так же становится невидимой. В чем проблема? Почему прячутся ImageSpan'ы?

p.s. в первой строке используется вот такой метод

```
private int getDrawableSmileResource(String name) {
    if(name.equals("thumb") || name.equals("thumbup") || name.equals("specool"))
        name = "up";
    if(name.equals("victory"))
        name = "v";
    if(name.equals("sleep"))
        name = "sleeping";
    if(name.equals("shades"))
        name = "cool";
    if(name.equals("santahat") || name.equals("santa"))
        name = "xmas";
    if(name.equals("sadwalk"))
        name = "sad";
    if(name.equals("rockon"))
        name = "serenade";
    int drawableId = R.drawable.smile_unknown;
    try {
        Class<drawable> res = R.drawable.class;
        Field field = res.getField("smile_" + name);
        drawableId = field.getInt(null);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        drawableId = R.drawable.smile_unknown;
        //Log.e("myLogs", "Failure to get drawable id.smile_", e);
    }
    return drawableId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю поможет ли это вам, но вот мой код, который ищет в строке подстроки и заменяет их на изображения, вроде работает)

```
public void addSpan(SpannableString ss, int res, String strSpan) {//Текст,  изображение, заменяемая подстрока
    int num = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    while (num != -1) {
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(res);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
        num = ss.toString().indexOf(strSpan, pos);
        pos += strSpan.length();
        if (num != -1) {
            ss.setSpan(span, num, num + strSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: жаль, но мне не подойдет((